# Correct usage of "getInstance" and static methods in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm a bit unclear on the correct use of static methods in PHP.

In the below scenario:

```
<?php

class Person 
{
    public $data;

    public function __construct($id) 
    {
        // Fetch record from our data source
        switch($id){
            case 1:
                $this->data = array('id'=>1, 'name'=>'Mike');
                break;
            case 2:
                $this->data = array('id'=>2, 'name'=>'Jennifer');
                break;
            default:
                exit('Record not found!');
        }
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->data['name'];
    }

    public static function getInstance($id)
    {
        return new self($id);
    }
} 

?>
```

I then output the names "Mike" and "Jennifer":

**Example A**

```
<?php 

foreach(array(1,2) as $id) 
    echo Person::getInstance($id)->getName(); 

?>
```

**Example B**

```
<?php 

foreach(array(1,2) as $id){
    $person = new Person($id);
    echo $person->getName();
}

?>
```

Either will print "MikeJennifer", but I was told **Example A** is wrong, "because Person is not a static class".

A class can't be declared "static" in PHP though, so why should it matter?

Comment: "but I was told Example A is wrong" --- it's not. The person who told it to you is wrong.

Comment: Why is the person wrong? First snippet looks like a singleton pattern. It doesn't seem to be needed in this case...

Comment: This class would still allow for multiple instances. So it looks like a bad implementation of a Singleton. Some sort of hybrid class

Comment: @One Trick Pony: the person is wrong because the explanation "because Person is not a static class" is wrong. It makes no sense.

Comment: Yeah, the method name is misleading. `getInstance` is usually used for singletons :) I guess it's fine if you change the name to something more appropriate and `self` with `static`. But still kind of pointless. Why not use the constructor

Comment: Having a single point of object creation is a very nice thing to have. That `::getInstance()` method could be in a dedicated factory class, or it can be a method of the `Person` class itself. If I had to choose between (a) and (b), I'd go (a) every time.

Comment: @One Trick Pony: why not use arrays for this case then? :-) It's not possible to talk about design decisions using oversimplified examples

Comment: Solution A does not scale very well, every time you use `Person::getInstance($id)`, you create a new instance of your class. As soon as you start getting the information from a database, you don't want to call `Person::getInstance($id)` for the same ID multiple times in different places.

Comment: @jeroen: Solution B also creates a new `Person` instance every loop iteration.

Comment: @jeroen: that is the _good_ thing about method (a), if _something_ needs to change about instantiation of `Person` classes, it can now be done in _one_ place in the code, rather then hundreds of `new Person()` calls all around the codebase.

Comment: @zerkms In the simplified example, yes, but when you use A to display the name, you might be tempted to use A to display the address somewhere else.

Comment: @Wrikken I agree, but using it like `echo Person::getInstance($id)->getName();` might suggest that is is the right way to echo out stuff. If you use it as a one-time factory, that's a different story of course. But you probably would not be outputting information there.

Comment: @jeroen: I'm missing your point. Neither of solutions `new` or this sort of factory uses any persistence for the created object. So they behave similarly and I personally don't see any difference between them. If you want to reuse object - you would just `$obj = Person::getInstance($id);` and that's it. No one requires OP to chain method calls.

Comment: @zerkms See my comment right before yours.

Comment: @jeroen: the original question was about "if it's OK to use static methods" and wasn't about methods chaining.

Comment: @zerkms Right, and my comment is just a comment - not an answer - to warn against potential misuse of A using the example the OP gave. I know A can be very useful but I also know things get copied-and-pasted a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In "Emergent Design", Scott L Bain describes this as a first-step pattern in abstracting the creation of objects.

Day 1: No abstraction...

```
$person = new Person($id);
```

Day 2: a static method to build the object for you...

```
$person = Person::getPerson($id);
```

Why? Because now you only have one piece of code in your entire application that knows how to "new up" a person, rather than having many lines of code distributed amongst your entire application that have that knowledge. If you change how you build a person object in the future, you will be able to just change the `getPerson` static method.

Day 3+: you may decide to lean on an object builder or repository for creating the object. When you choose to do this, you could update your `getPerson` static method to use the builder / repository and once again the change happens in just one place.

This is called "cohesion". Having code where you can make changes without having to open lots of files.

Comment: Not to disagree, this seems interesting, but what's the difference between altering the `getPerson` method and just altering the `Person` constructor?

Comment: @Wesley Murch: this may shed some light: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern

Comment: If you use `new Person($id)` throughout your code (say, 20 times) you need to change the constructor 20 times. Using `Person::getPerson($id)` you don't have to change that code. For example, if I needed to pass a dependency into `new Person` I wouldn't have to create and pass the dependency in 20 places, just one.

Comment: @zerkms Thank you but to be honest it doesn't clarify it for me as I'm not familiar with the "telescoping constructor anti-pattern". Any chance it can be explained in laymen's terms?

Comment: @SteveFenton Thanks, it's not clear to me still but I'll chew on that a while.

Comment: @Wesley Murch: treat it as an abstraction from the way the object creation, which may be not-trivial or changing often.

Comment: @zerkms To me it seems like abstraction for the sake of abstraction, but then again I'm more of a "PHP guy" and less of a "programmer". I'm guessing this is tied directly to dependency injection, and avoiding `new` in constructors?

Comment: @Wesley Murch: I agree for this example it's not a straightforward and expected design decision, but it's a simplification http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17478482/correct-usage-of-getinstance-and-static-methods-in-php#comment25401134_17478542

Comment: Some very good related material: [a talk about OO Design for testability](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=acjvKJiOvXw)

Comment: Erm, wrong link, [this one of the same guy was the one I meant](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlfLCWKxHJ0)

Comment: To put my answer in context, I'm not saying "do this no matter what". I just wanted to make it clear that it is a known pattern. It isn't an anti-pattern. Use your programming knowledge to decide when it is appropriate.

Comment: In fact, instead of calling a constructor to create the object and access to it using a getter, we only use one getter to either create the object or get it.